# Convert Uri to absolute path with dart

Tags: dart, path, uri, absolute-path

I only get one uri from the file_picker when saving. But so that I can display the correct path, I need the absolute path of the file. Unfortunately I haven't found a working solution. The library flutter_absolute_path unfortunately doesn't seem to work with the new Android versions anymore.
Does anyone have any idea how I could get the absolute path of the file.

example:

- content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/297
- convert to:
- /data/user/0/xxx/cache/dummy1.png

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **toFilePath()** method of the dart:core package to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I thought so too. But unfortunately I get an exception.

test code:

```
//uri output from file picker (fileInfo.identifier)
var uriPath = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/297";
var uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
print(uri.toFilePath());
```

exception
-> Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a file path from a content URI